# why am i getting 22 / 3 itprog~1.pas Fatal: Syntax error, ; expected but ELSE found

Tags: pascal

```
PROGRAM approvedapplicants(input,output);
uses crt;
var
applcntname,housingcomm,clarendon_court,providence_gardens,
sangre_grande_villas:string;
slry,spcslry:integer;
c_qual_sal,s_qual_sal,p_qual_sal,qualifying_salary:integer;

BEGIN
writeln('enter applicant name, salary, spouce salary');
readln(applcntname,slry,spcslry);
writeln('enter housing community');
readln(housingcomm);
BEGIN
qualifying_salary:=0;
IF(housingcomm=clarendon_court)
then
qualifying_salary:=$12500;
writeln('you have selected clarendon court!');
readln(c_qual_sal) ;
end if  ;

  else if(housingcomm=sangre_grande_villas)then
  qualifying_salary:=$9500;
  writeln('you have selected sangre grande villas!');
  readln(s_qual_sal);
  end if ;

  else(housingcomm=providence_gardens)then;
  qualifying_salary:=$7500;
  writeln('you have selected providence gardens!');
  readln(p_qual_sal);
  end if;
  END.
```

Comment: You need to learn the structure of if then, and [if then else](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.0/ref/refsu58.html). You have too many `if`'s and `;`'s in your code, and you are missing some `begin`'s.

Comment: In addition to what @DavidA said, in Pascal there's nothing like `end if`.

Comment: You really need to learn Pascal grammar - your code is riddled with mistakes and maybe misunderstandings..  It has no `end if` construct - an `end` usually goes with a `begin` (there are exceptions, but `if` isn't one one them).  There is no `else xxx then` and a `then` followed by  semi-colon will do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Ordinarily, on SO, we don't post answers to homework/coursework, but your code is so far wide of the mark that I think it's ok to make an exception in this case.

Try compiling and running this program, which I think does pretty much what I think you are intending, then I'll explain a few things about it:

```
program approvedapplicants(input,output);
uses crt;

var
  ApplicantName,
  HousingCommunity,
  ClarendonCourt,
  ProvidenceGardens,
  SangreGrandVillas :string;
  Salary,
  SpouseSalary,
  QualifyingSalary : Integer;
  CQualSal,
  PQualSal,
  SQualSal : Integer;
  slry,spcslry:integer;

begin
  ClarendonCourt := 'Clarendon Court';
  ProvidenceGardens := 'Providence Gardens';
  SangreGrandVillas := 'Sangre Grand Villas';
  QualifyingSalary := 0;

  writeln('enter applicant name');
  readln(ApplicantName);

  writeln('enter salary');
  readln(Salary);

  writeln('enter spouse salary');
  readln(SpouseSalary);

  writeln('enter housing community');
  readln(HousingCommunity);

  if (HousingCommunity = ClarendonCourt) then begin
    QualifyingSalary := $12500;
    writeln('you have selected clarendon court!');
    readln(CQualSal);
  end
  else
    if(HousingCommunity = SangreGrandVillas)then begin
      QualifyingSalary := $9500;
      writeln('you have selected sangre grande villas!');
      readln(SQualSal);
    end
    else
    if HousingCommunity = ProvidenceGardens then begin
      QualifyingSalary :=$7500;
      writeln('you have selected providence gardens!');
      readln(CQualSal);
    end;

end.
```

Firstly, notice how much easier it is to read and follow its logic.  This is mainly
because of

- The use of a layout (including indented blocks) which reflects the logical
  structure of the code.
- The use of consistent, lower case for keywords like `program`, `begin`, `end`, etc.
  Keywords are usually the least interesting contents of source code, and it is distracting
  to have them SHOUTing at you.
- The avoidance of arbitrarily dropping characters from variable names (like the "i"
  and second "a" of "applicant".  In the days of interpreted code running on slow machines there was
  argubably some justification for this, but not any more imo.  Likewise, the avoidance
  of underscores in variable names - admittedly this is more of a personal preference, but
  why have you used them everywhere except the applicant's name?

Secondly, you still have quite a bit of work to do.

- Having 3 different variables for the salary (?) numbers you prompt the user
  for, one for each of the 3 communities, is probably a bad idea unless you will
  subsequently want to work with all 3 figures at the same time.  Also, you haven't provided text prompts to tell the user what information to enter for the `readln(c_qual_sal)` etc statements.  It wasn't obvious to me what you intend, so I have not tried to guess.
- The way you echo the user's choice of community is just creating you a maintenance
  headache (what if you want to add more communities later?).  It would be better
  to have a variable which you set to whichever of the community names matches
  what the user has entered.
- You have 3 statements to execute for each community, which are duplicated for
  each community.  The only one you actually need is the QualifyingSalary one -
  the others can execute regardless of the inputted community.

Comment: Well, or he simply didn't try and waits for gullible people to solve it for him. Or he shops around http://forum.lazarus-ide.org/index.php/topic,36060.msg240005/topicseen.html#new